# Primeng and Angular 2 controllers validation

Tags: validation, angular, primeng

I'm new to the primeng controllers and I'm stuck on the validation of some complex controllers for example the spinner controller. I want to set this controller to required and using ReactiveFormsModule I'm able to set the proper validation. however, I noticed that although he have the angular classes like this

```
<p-spinner formControlName="myspinner" class="ng-dirty ng-touched ng-invalid">
```

the inner input isn't affected by it, and this is a problem because the prime css is written to affect the input field.
 Is possible to resolve this by writing a little more css, but is suppose to be like this?? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand why the inner input field is not affected by the validation, but in my case it was a easy fix.
what I ended up doing was, set the css to change the border-color of the input child

```
 p-spinner.ng-dirty.ng-invalid .ui-inputtext {
  border-bottom-color: #f44336;
}
```

This was enough  for me.